# pymssql.connect error - unexpected keyword argument 'server'

Tags: import, module, kernel, connect, pymssql

I'm trying to run a program I've made but am having issues. It's stating there is an error on line 8? It was working the other day and I'm not sure if it has been changed. Is this an connection error to the database perhaps??

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import time
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect (server='192.168.0.223', user='iad', password='iad',database='inputData')
cursor = conn.cursor()
#cursor.execute('select * from yesno')
#row = cursor.fetchone()
#while row:
#       print str(row[0])
#       row = cursor.fetchone()

print("Welcome! Button live data:")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(18)
        input_state2 = GPIO.input(23)
        if input_state == False:
                print('Happy')
                print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO buttonsPressed (inputResult, date) VALUES ('yes', '" + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "')")
                conn.commit()
                time.sleep(1)

        if input_state2 == False:
                print('Not Happy')
                print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO buttonsPressed (inputResult, date) VALUES ('no', '" + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "')")
                conn.commit()
                time.sleep(1)
```

I'm getting this error?:

```
File "buttonin.py", line 8, in <module>
    conn = pymssql.connect (server='192.168.0.223', user='iad', password='iad',database='inputData')
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server'
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use host="" instead of server=""

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error.

Try upgrading the python pymssql library.

In Ubuntu you can upgrade it by following commands:
1. sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
2. pip install pymssql --upgrade

Hope this helps you.